# Is redundant data always a no-go

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm working on a shop-like system (in PHP & MySQL) that exports invoices to an external system. The proces goes something like this;

- Customer orders a product and an invoice is created
- XML is generated for this invoice and sent to the external server
- External server handles XML and responds with another XML
- System handles response.

For every XML that's being sent to the external server a record is created in the database containing the corresponding invoicenumber and a status (status is initially `SENT`, indicating that the XML is sent.) After the system has handled the response the status is either `SUCCESS` or `ERROR`. Now, the problem is; at some point I want to fetch a list of invoices that have no record in the request table with status `SUCCESS`.

EDIT: If the status is `ERROR` there will be a new request for the same invoice, so there is a possibility that there will be more than one request per invoice.

My order table has columns `ID` and `InvoiceNumber`, and the request table has columns `ID`, `InvoiceNumber` and `Status`, so to get the list mentioned I could do something like:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber 
FROM orders AS a
LEFT JOIN requests AS b
    ON a.InvoiceNumber = b.InvoiceNumber
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID 
                       FROM requests 
                       WHERE status = "SUCCESS" 
                           AND request.InvoiceNumber = a.InvoiceNumber)
```

However, a second option would be to create an extra column to the order table (ie. `requestSucces`) being initially 0 and set to 1 if the system handles a successful response for the corresponding invoice. This would result in a much easier and less expensive query to get the list of invoices that need to be (re)sent (`SELECT invoiceNumber FROM orders WHERE requestSuccess = 0`), however the field would technically be redundant.

My question is: what would be better; use the easy query at the cost of having a redundant field or use the heavier query and not pollute the database with redundancy. Of course; if any of you know of a better solution without using redundancy that would be even better.

Comment: this seems pretty subjective to me - personally I don't consider it redundant if it results in a fast query vs a slow query - however I'm not a DBA and I'm sure plenty would offer a different point of view

Comment: I would consider denormalising the data as you suggest if it avoids a heavy query although you might consider other ways of optimising. Are there multiple requests per invoice (it's not 100% clear from your question)?

Comment: @liquorvicar; I've updated my question; there is a possibility that there are more than one requests per invoice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you make the status field numeric error=0 and succes=1 one you could do a max status grouped by invoicenumber to see which invoices are no

Comment: This option crossed my mind, however; there are more statusses (`SENT` being one I mentioned in the question, but there are others). Do you think it would be an option to give them all a number and let `SUCCESS` be the highest?

Comment: I think it depends on the number of states and how you are combining them. If you only have send,succes and error I think you can go this way. If you will be adding more states in the future you have to prepare that you are not conflicting the max with new states

Comment: I think I will be going to use something like this.

Comment: Or make success 0 and group by min(status). Depends if you can handle success being represented by a zero!

Comment: Inspired by this answer I'm going to go with a numeric representation of each status.

Answer (score 0):

Wars have been fought over normalization :-)

But:
Since you're looking for invoices that are not set to `success`, couldn't you do this?

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber
FROM requests 
WHERE status != "SUCCESS"
```

(Note the not equal symbol)

Comment: Hi Patches, thanks for your reply, but since there could be more than one request per invoice this wouldn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Given that from the info you provide it seems there will always be at least one entry in your Requests table for each Invoice you could get the data you need from a query like this:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber
FROM Requests AS r_error
LEFT JOIN Requests AS r_success
ON (r_error.InvoiceNumber=r_success.InvoiceNumber AND r_error.status!='SUCCESS'
    AND r_success.status='SUCCESS')
WHERE r_success.InvoiceNumber IS NULL
```

I'm not sure it would be lightning fast but I think it would be quicker than your initial query (I haven't tested that theory!) but more importantly it doesn't use your Orders table so shouldn't impact your transaction processing as much.